# is there any packages in solidity to encrypt the message using wallet's public key in smart contract?

Tags: solidity

**is there any packages in solidity to encrypt the message using wallet's public key in smart contract ?**

I need to encrypt the message using wallet's public key and I have to encrypt by eth_decrypt method on UI to decrypt it.

Is it possible ? or any work around?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need the private key to encrypt?

Comment: Usually encryption/decryption is done at the wallet level because everything on the blockchain is public. Unfortunately there is no EIP related to encryption that was accepted by everyone.